# fetch JSON data asynchronously

Tags: iphone, json, asynchronous

I want to fetch JSON data asynchronously. The data is set up in a way that one request will bring only 8 records. I need to send the requests repeatedly until the response becomes empty or returns less than 8 records.

Currently, I have these methods in myviewcontroller.m class:

```
(void)myCallback:(id)sender {

    MyDataRequest *objMyDataRequest = [[[MyDataRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    objMyDataRequest.myRequiredVariableToGetAuthTokenDataResponse = classOfMyCallBack.someVariable;

    // Initiate getAuthToken request
    [objWishListRequest initiateGetAuthTokenRequest:self requestSelector:@selector(getAuthTokenDataResponse:)];
}
```

Now here is the definition of getAuthTokenDataResponse:

```
(void) getAuthTokenDataResponse:(NSData *)data {

    NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *objDictionaryForStringResponse = [parser objectWithString:stringResponse];
    [stringResponse release];
    [parser release];
    MyListRequest *objMyListRequest = [[[MyListRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    objMyListRequest.myRequiredValueToGetMyDataResponse = [objDictionaryForStringResponse objectForKey:@"Data"]; 

    // Initiate GetMyDataResponse request
    [objMyListRequest initiateGetMyDataRequest:self requestSelector:@selector(getMyDataResponse:)]; 

}


(void) getMyDataResponse:(NSData *)data {

    NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *objGetMyDataRootDictionary = [parser objectWithString:stringResponse];
    [stringResponse release];
    [parser release];
    NSDictionary *dataElements=[objGetMyDataRootDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"];
    Wish *objMyData; 

    for (NSDictionary* objGetMyDataRootDictionary in dataElements) {
        objMyData = [[Wish alloc]init];
        //add different elements from dataElements into member variables of object objWish
        [self.myDataArray addObject:objMyData];
        [objMyData release];
    }
    [self.myDataTableView reloadData];
}
```

This method lies in MyDataRequest class:

```
(void)initiateGetMyDataRequest:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector{

    // Set the delegate and selector
    self.delegate = requestDelegate;
    self.callback = requestSelector;

    NSString* unescapedUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.mytesturl.com/core.svc/alldata/My/get/All/?token=%@&search=&page=1",myRequiredtokenparameter];  
    [self request:url];
}
```

I need to send multiple requests to the same url (with different parameter value i.e. value of page number) to fetch the results. How may I achieve it given the above scenario? The calls must be asynchronous.

How should I make the actual flow between all these calls? How may I get the data of "all the pages" asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a operation queue. I use `ASIHTTPRequests` in my apps and they work.

If you want to use this library, here's the link how to use it: [Show UIActivityIndicatorView when loading NSString from Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595315/show-uiactivityindicatorview-when-loading-nsstring-from-web/6596024#6596024)

Comment: sorry just noticed that you sent reply to my question. I thought, i'll get an email when a reply will be posted here. Anyway, I have figured out most of the stuff. Left with minor issues like how to handle the scrolling on UITableView. Asked about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050659/need-sample-code-to-implement-paging-based-uiscrollview/7050791#7050791) if you can help me out.