# Need sample code to implement Paging Based UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, web-services, uiscrollview

I am new to iOS development. Can anyone give me a working sample project/ tutorial of paging based scrollview? I need to load more data in my table view from a webservice as user scrolls down. 
I have spent a lot of time, but could not find anything that suits my need. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I was able to figure out the solution of my problem. Now I am trying to detect scroll up and down based on the y offset difference. The problem is it always reads the drag to be downwards even if it is upward. This is how I am trying to detect the scroll direction:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    CGPoint scrollOffSet =  scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"Current Content offset: , y = %f", scrollOffSet.y);
    NSLog(@"Previous offset , y = %f", self.previousYOffset);

    if(scrollOffSet.y > self.previousYOffset)
    {
        self.previousYOffset = scrollOffSet.y;
        NSLog(@"Scrolled Down");
        self.nextPageNumber++;
        //Here I send the request to fetch data for next page number
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Scrolled up");
        self.previousYOffset = scrollOffSet.y;
    }

}


- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    CGPoint scrollOffSet =  scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"Current Content offset: y = %f", scrollOffSet.y);
}
```

The problem is: either i scroll up or down, it will always display "scrolled down", thus it goes to fetch data for next page number even if it was not intended to request. Plus, the y offset positions it returns on up/down scroll are also very confusing. Please guide me how to accurately detect an upside scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a "swipable" `UIScrollView`?

Paging a `UIScrollView` is quite easy. First make sure you have the `pagingEnabled` property set to `YES`. The `UIScrollView` will use it's own frame as the size of a page (like a viewport).

Use the `contentSize` property to determine the `scrollable area`.

Example:

```
//scrollView is a UIScrollView instance  
int pageCount = 3;  
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;  
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width*pageCount, scrollView.frame.height);
```

Comment: I want to read scroll event on a UITableView, not really swipable. I fetch data to display on one page. Then, as the user scrolls down, next set of data (a page containing 8 records) has to be fetched through API call. 
What I have done so far is like this.

Comment: First, please note that I am not using any UIScrollView control on the nib file associated with my viewcontroller.

I am trying to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate with my UIViewController.

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
// Here i am sending the "asynchronous" call to fetch data for next page. 
//Incrementing the page number
}

Comment: What is happening is… When a user scrolls down, it keeps on invoking the scrollViewDidScroll method so that it calls the method around 50 times. But my data is far less. I want to call it just for one next page. Is there any way that scrollViewDisScroll should be called just once?

Comment: No, but you can use the `contentOffset` property and check to see if the user scrolled down the list far enough to fetch new data.